# iOS swipe to delete cell suddenly come back to normal state

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swipe

I am trying to implement swipe to delete gesture.

Sometimes after do the swipe gesture the cell come back to normal state in a forced way.
Entering on edit mode and tapping on the - button it occurs too.

It happens randomly.

This method is called always when user tap edit button:

```
- (IBAction)editButtonTapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];
}
```

`canEditRowAtIndexPath` method always return `YES`. And this is my `commitEditingStyle` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete object from database
        [context deleteObject:[self.alarmsMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            return;
        }

        // Remove object from table view
        [self.alarmsMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}
```

Comment: Look anywhere in your code that does a reloadData or it's subset companions on this tableview. Very likely you have a notification or some other trigger happening asynchronously, giving the appearance of randomness.

Comment: I'm passing UITableViewRowAnimationFade in the withRowAnimation parameter. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @BradBrighton thank you very much!
I was calling reloadData when receiving location update. My app is based on the user location.

Answer (score -1):

you need to nest the removal of item from model and from tableView in an update block
so before your last two lines of code there put..

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
```

and then at the end put..

```
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

......
note that in between those last two lines there you model is out of sync with your tableView (you've removed an object from the array, but not yet removed a cell...)  you should only ever be in this position in between [  beginUpdates] and [  endUpdates] or your app can crash.

Comment: No, you don't need to do this. You only need `begin/endUpdate` when making multiple calls to `delete/insert/reloadRows`. Besides, if the cell is automatically going back to normal after a swipe, the `commitEditingStyle` isn't even getting called.